# How to predict cumulative hazard in survival analysis?

Tags: r, survival

Suppose I have a survival model like this:

```
set.seed(123)
require(survival)
df<-data.frame(time=as.integer(rnorm(100,50,5)), 
               status=rbinom(100,1,0.7), 
               age=rnorm(100,60, 5), 
               gender=rbinom(100,1,0.5))
df$time<-ifelse(df$time>=50,50,df$time)

coxfit<-coxph(Surv(time, status)~age+gender, data=df)
aftfit<-survreg(Surv(time, status)~age+gender, data=df, dist="exponential")
```

if there's a subject with `age=32`, `gender=1`, how could I predict his cumulative hazard($\hat{H}(t)$) during a fixed time interval, say (16,50], using the `coxfit` and/or `aftfit`?